# Number of permutations of 6 digit numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Number of permutations of $6 $digit numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that the pattern $12, 23 ,34 ,45, 56$ do not appear is?

I observed that if we take the above permutation as a function in variable $n$ (number of digits given; 6 in above case) then, given $n>2$,
$$f(n)=(n-1)f(n-1)+(n-2)f(n-2)$$
for example:
$f(3)$=Number of permutations of 3 digit numbers from {1,2,3} such that the pattern 12,23
does not appear
I got $f(3)=3$ (tell me if Iam wrong)
$f(4)=11$
as from above formula i got $f(5)=53$ which is correct
so can anyone tell me the original process for this question please.

Comment: You say $f(3)=3$. Which $3$ permutations are those? (It's easier for us to tell whether you're right or wrong if you show us your work, not just your answers.)

Comment: @Arthur I suspect 132,213,321.

Comment: 132,213,321 are the answers I got for f(3)

Comment: What do you mean with the "original process"?

Comment: I mean how do we get that equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ denote the number of feasible permutations of the numbers $1...n$ and let $g(n)$ denote the number of permutations of these numbers that contain exactly one disallowed pair (a pattern $(k,k+1)$ for some $k$ with $1\le k\le n-1$).

To build a feasible permutation for the numbers $1...n$, we can either start with a feasible permutation of the numbers $1...(n-1)$ and place the number $n$ somwhere in between/around, except directly after number $n-1$ (there are $n-1$ possible positions), or we start with a permutation of $n-1$ elements that contains exactly one disallowed pair $(k,k+1)$ and place the number $n$ between $k$ and $k+1$ (to "destroy" the disallowed pair). In total, we get
$$
f(n)=(n-1)f(n-1)+g(n-1)
$$
Now, to construct a permutation of the $n$ numbers that contains exactly one disallowed pair $(k,k+1)$, we can do the following: Choose any $k$ from $1...(n-1)$ and start with a feasible permutation of the $n-1$ numbers $1...(n-1)$. In this permutation, add $1$ to all numbers greater than $k$ and place $k+1$ directly after $k$. This process can be reversed to receive a feasible permutation of $n-1$ elements from any $n$-permutation with exactly one disallowed pair, so
$$
g(n)=(n-1)f(n-1)
$$
Putting both together, we indeed get
$$
f(n)=(n-1)f(n-1)+g(n-1)=(n-1)f(n-1)+(n-2)f(n-2)
$$

Comment: I am confused with the first equation u got can u elaborate, please

Comment: @CharanT: The first equation adds the number of ways to construct a feasible $n$-permutation by either extending a feasible $(n-1)$-permutation or by destroying the disallowed pair in a permutation containing exactly one such disallowed pair. For the first case, in each feasible $(n-1)$-permutation there are $n-1$options for placing the new element $n$, so this makes $(n-1)f(n-1)$ possible constructions. The second case is counted using my helper-function $g$.

Comment: but why are we adding both cases, my doubt is that we are using "or" in between two functions then how do we add them?

Comment: @CharanT The "or" is an "exclusive or", because the permutations we count in both cases are mutually exclusive. Removing number $n$ from a first-case permutation yields a feasible $(n-1)$-permutation, while doing so with a second-case permutation leaves an $(n-1)$-permutation that contains a (exactly one) forbidden pair. ("feasible" means "not containing a forbidden pair")

Comment: Now I understood thank u